# Is there any way to debug an error creating a plugin?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have stepped through both tutorials that I could find for creating phonegap plugins:

1. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html
2. http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS

and in both cases when I run the example absolutely nothing happens. I assume this is b/c I am running into an error in the javascript. Is there any way at all for me to get information about what this error is? Some way to catch exceptions or anything?

Thank you for your time,

-- Henry

Comment: If you can test in Chrome or IE and pop open the console F12 (FireFox requires FireBug), you can check for obvious Javascript errors. If not, the easiest is to throw an `alert()` at the end of the code to see if it's at least loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using weinre it is a really good tool to debug javascript applications on mobile devices. While running your application you can see all the errors (if any) in the console window of the tool.

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Phonegap even has a server set up for this: http://debug.phonegap.com/